# Adding multiple children to the stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm a new flash developer.  I have read here http://www.flashandmath.com/intermediate/children/stage.html that I should avoid adding children to the stage itself and only add them to my MainTimeLine derived main document class (which is itself a child of stage).  However, the author does not give explanation/justification for this approach.

I am developing a project where I am considering adding UI popup windows to the stage directly rather than including them in my MainTimeline (it makes it easier to keep them above everything else and also makes it easier for me to know what I need to persist and what I don't when saving).

What are the downsides of this?  Is it a "bad practice" in Flash?  Why?

Answer (score 0):

For quick demos and presentations I often use the Flash IDE's timeline to manage my depths. I create empty movieClips and put them on the different layers. For example, my top layer would be my Popup Layer, under that would be my Main Content Layer, under that would be my Background Layer. My main document class manages the adding and removing of popups, content and background instances.

I believe it is bad practice to add children directly to the Stage. Here is a decent thread explaining some differences between [MainTimeLine vs stage.](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=213491)